# Mathematica Looping through a block of cells

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In mathematica, one can write loops using `For` or `While` within a cell similar to other programming languages. In order to run a block of cells iteratively, the best way I could come up with is to write the loop in a separated mathematica notebook and call `NotebookOpen; SelectionEvaluate`. Is there any way to run a block of cells iteratively without creating extra notebook file?

Thanks

Comment: You can still run SelectionEvaluate even without creating a separate notebook.

Comment: Is there anything like "GOTO label", if it does, I can certainly use SelectionEvaluate within the notebook

Comment: @LebronJames, yes indeed Mathematica has GOTO statment. I would use that and jump to the labels. Make sure that you add a label at the top of each cell to jump to, preferably in the same cell to avoid any confusion. One of the advantages of Mathematica is that it is flexible computational engine which allows and encourages the use of many different programming methods (unlike other systems). I encourage you to explore GOTO more and experiment with the many different programming aspects of Mathematica, including LOOPS and DO if you are more familiar with those.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for `Module`?

```
doTheLoop[] :=
  Module[{a, i},
    a = {};
    For[i=1, i < 1000, i++, If[PrimeQ[i], AppendTo[a, i]]];
    a
  ]
```

call the subroutine with `doTheLoop[]`

Generally however [loops are not the way to go](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121) with *Mathematica*.